# Unable insert row using Hibernate if double quotes are used

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

For fail safe am always using double quotes in my mapping class. And this only for **PostgreSQL**

Here is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="`Person`"
   ,schema="public"
)
public class Person  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public Person() {
    }


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="`ID`", nullable=false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="`Name`")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="`Address`")
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

When am trying insert using Am getting below exception:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name`ID`was not found in this ResultSet.`

Query it ran for insert was:

`insert into public."Person" ("Address", "Name") values (?, ?)`

I can't remove double quotes for other reasons.

Please help me to get this problem fixed.

Update: 
Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "Person"
(
    "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Person_ID_seq"'::regclass),
    "Name" VARCHAR(255),
    "Address" VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Comment: In the table, the name of column is "ID"?

Comment: Yes, column name is "ID"

Comment: use `@Column(name="\"ID\"", nullable=false)`

Comment: @Dmitry Yep. Using block quote ` does same job. after insert returned Result Set does not contain **"ID"** it just had **ID**

Comment: could you please provide DDL from Postgres for this table? run `\d "Person"` in psql

Comment: Sorry @Dmitry, Am accessing that database remotely. i don't have system access to execute that command.

Comment: "*For fail safe am using*" - it would be **much** safer (=a lot less problems) if you **never** used double quotes.

Comment: I sense a bug when fetching generated ID values from case sensitive columns in Hibernate, here...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually am working on to generate code from database schema. it is safer for me to use block quotes, this will reduce my conditions for reserved keywords and space handling.

Comment: Honestly: you should _really_ avoid quoted identifiers (Also: those are called "double" quotes, not "block" quotes). The problem from your question is just the tip of the iceberg

Comment: `name="\`Name\`"` is completely wrong by the way. Backticks are illegal in an SQL identifier

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes. hibernate will handle based on database separator type if we give block quotes(backticks).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes sql won't support. hibernate will replace backticks while creating queries.

Comment: @LukasEder your correct. This is working fine for fetching data. And it is there only for insert day and that too if we have auto increment. While debugging i found that hibernate looking for value with key `"ID"` but in resultset it had only `ID`. Same code working for **MySQL** database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: 1) that's how JPA works. Backticks. I know... But the OP's code is correct. 2) the schema is outside of the OP's reach. It happens. Legacy systems. Restrictive DBA. Etc. It's OK, too. Just a bug in a library. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

If everything need to be quoted, add the following flags to hibernate.properties or persistence.xml file

```
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
```

and remove all the single quote from the class Person. However, take note that for Postgresql, placing table/column name etc in double quote effectively turn them into case sensitives. So the case for the table/column in the database must be exact match of the corresponding name in the @Table and @Column annotation.