# Hibernate: Can't insert a row using "identity" id generation with qouted column name

Tags: hibernate

I have the same issue explained here [Unable insert row using Hibernate if double quotes are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34633985/unable-insert-row-using-hibernate-if-double-quotes-are-used) when I try to insert a record using identity strategy generation, I debugged and  I found that hibernate looking for value with key "ID" but in ResultSet fields had only ID.

It's required that my column name is quoted. 
I tried:
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
Any idea please? Thank you